# Checking characters and character order from input form using Javascript to display images that match both character and character order

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, for-loop, indexof

I am creating a simple system that will display images according letters found in the text input form. For example, if the user inputs the letter "p", the image with the id of #paris is shown. The example below works and accomplishes the first part of the goal.

```
  <input id="words" name="email" class="userInput" type="text" /><span id="emailError"></span>
  <br>
  <br>
      <div id="Button" style="height:100px; width: 150px; background-color: #000;">
        </div>
<img id="paris" style="display:none" src="animsAll/paris.gif">
```

Jquery

```
$( "#words" ).keyup(function() {

if ($('#words').val().indexOf('p') > -1) {
    $('#paris').show();
```

}

```
});
```

**However, one crucial element is missing.**

When I add more images (there will be 6 images to choose from), **the system needs to display these images according to the order in which the user typed the word.**

**Meaning, f the user typed "peter" the image that corresponds to "p" would display for a few seconds and then hide, and then the image that connects to "e" would display thereafter.** [Hiding and setting timing is not the issue.]

**My question really is about sorting the character order so that the images are displayed in the order in which the user typed. How does the system understand the order of each letter so that images are displayed in the same order as the letters are?**

I understand IndexOf in set of known strings, but in the case of input forms, where the possibilities are infinite, how do I sort the characters found in the user input (in the example,  "P, e, t, e, r" so that the system will display the order of images correctly?

---

**[ONE DAY LATER: THANK YOU FOR THE ANSWER & QUESTION UPDATE]**

Thank you!!! Now that i have worked out the problem further, I realize I may have misrepresented my question. Perhaps I should ask a different question. **What I am *really* doing here, is a form of animation lip-sync. I have created (animation)characters and I have the corresponding mouth movements according each letter for a lip-sync.**

Although the question addresses this issue, it's possible that instead of creating separate images, I am better off creating an animation using a sprite image as opposed to separate images.There are seven possible variables per frame.

---

**[UPDATED ISSUE]**

**What happens now, is that the letters match the images, show up all at the same time. Also, the order in which the images appear corresponds to the order displayed on the html, not the actual user input. You can see the example shown in the image below, where I wrote "Peter" and the system returned four separate images. It is missing the second "e" image, on top of that.**

Thank you guys for the answers I will do a bit more research on this. I can see the direction I need to go.

**[SEE IMAGE BELOW]**

[image: "peter" entered]

**[HTML]**

```
  <img id="heatherCatPaw1AI" style="display:none" src="img_chars/Heather_catPaw_1_A,I.svg">
  <img id="heatherCatPaw1E" style="display:none" src="img_chars/Heather_catPaw_1_E.svg">
  <img id="heatherCatPaw1MPB" style="display:none" src="img_chars/Heather_catPaw_1_M,P,B.svg">
  <img id="heatherCatPaw1O" style="display:none" src="img_chars/Heather_catPaw_1_O.svg">
  <img id="heatherCatPaw1TS" style="display:none" src="img_chars/Heather_catPaw_1_T,S,ELSE.svg">
  <img id="heatherCatPaw1UQ" style="display:none" src="img_chars/Heather_catPaw_1_U,Q.svg">
  <img id="heatherCatPaw1WR" style="display:none" src="img_chars/Heather_catPaw_1_W,R.svg">
```

**[JAVASCRIPT]**

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $.each($("#myinput").val().split(''), function(index, value) {
      if ($('#myinput').val().indexOf('a') > -1) {
        $('#heatherCatPaw1AI').show().delay(200).fadeOut();
      }

      if ($('#myinput').val().indexOf('i') > -1) {
        $('#heatherCatPaw1AI').show().delay(200).fadeOut();
      }

      if ($('#myinput').val().indexOf('e') > -1) {
      $('#heatherCatPaw1E').show().delay(200).fadeOut();
      }

      if ($('#myinput').val().indexOf('m') > -1) {
      $('#heatherCatPaw1MPB').show().delay(200).fadeOut();
      }

      if ($('#myinput').val().indexOf('p') > -1) {
      $('#heatherCatPaw1MPB').show().delay(200).fadeOut();
      }

      if ($('#myinput').val().indexOf('b') > -1) {
      $('#heatherCatPaw1MPB').show().delay(200).fadeOut();
      }

      if ($('#myinput').val().indexOf('o') > -1) {
      $('#heatherCatPaw1O').show().delay(200).fadeOut();
      }


      if ($('#myinput').val().indexOf('') > -1) {
      $('#heatherCatPaw1TS').show().delay(200).fadeOut();
      }

      if ($('#myinput').val().indexOf('s') > -1) {
      $('#heatherCatPaw1TS').show().delay(200).fadeOut();
      }

      if ($('#myinput').val().indexOf('u') > -1) {
      $('#heatherCatPaw1UQ').show().delay(200).fadeOut();
      }

      if ($('#myinput').val().indexOf('q') > -1) {
      $('#heatherCatPaw1UQ').show().delay(200).fadeOut();
      }

      if ($('#myinput').val().indexOf('w') > -1) {
      $('#heatherCatPaw1WR').show().delay(200).fadeOut();
      }
      if ($('#myinput').val().indexOf('r') > -1) {
      $('#heatherCatPaw1WR').show().delay(200).fadeOut();
      }

  });
```

Comment: provide example html result if user input PETER

Comment: $("#myinput").keyup(function() {
var myarray = $("#myinput").val.split('')
});

Comment: hi @plonknimbuzz I have added an update to the question.

Comment: hi @BryanDellinger thank you so much for your answer, I realize the question was incomplete on my end, I have now updated it. Nevertheless your great answer has pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: hi, why you still do this using indexof. do like bryan said in the answer below, much better

Answer (score 2):

use split to put the string into an array then loop through it and do whatever you want. (I would probably do it on something other than keyup or it will be firing all the time)

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $.each($("#myinput").val().split(''), function(index, value) {
    $('#myol').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="myinput">
<button id="btn">
 click me
</button>

<ol id="myol">

</ol>
```

Comment: i just know that we can do `split('')` +1

Comment: Thank you so much Bryan. Now that i have worked out the problem further, I realize I may have misrepresented my question. I updated the question above. Perhaps I should ask a different question. What I am really doing here, is a form of animation lip-sync. I have created (animation)characters and I have the corresponding mouth movements according each letter for a lip-sync.

Comment: What happens now, is that the letters match the images, show up all at the same time. Also, the order in which the images appear corresponds to the order displayed on the html, not the actual user input. You can see the example shown in the image I added to the updated question, where I wrote "Peter" and the system returned four separate images. It is missing the second "e" image, on top of that. Anyway thank you so much your answer is leading me in the right direction in my learning steps:)